# Running python3 from a usb drive (portably)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, dll, pygame, usb

I want to run python3 on our school computers (under Windows) during our programming classes. I installed python 3.1 onto a USB flash drive at home (using Windows), and brought it to school. However, it gives me the following error:

> The program can't start because python31.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

How do I get the file, where do I put it (can I put it onto the USB itself?) and/or is there a better alternative for python3 portability?
The reason why I don't simply use an online editor is because I also want to have pygame along with python on the USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed python on your home PC "for all users" the .dll is in the c:\windows\system32\ (or equivalent). 
Copy it to your USB drive folder or reinstall python "just for me" on the USB drive so it contains everything in one place.

Comment: Thank you, will try

Comment: into your python folder (on the usb drive)